# Create ul li from the object using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I face a problem to convert a JavaScript object into a multi level list element.

Input JavaScript Object

```
let data = [
   {level: 1, content: 'First Lvl', link:'#'},
   {level: 2, content: 'Second Lvl', link:'#'},
   {level: 3, content: 'Third Lvl', link:'#'},
   {level: 2, content: 'Second Lvl 2', link:'#'},
   {level: 1, content: 'First Lvl 2', link:'#'}
];
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">First Lvl</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second Lvl</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Lvl</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second Lvl 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">First Lvl 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I found a almost similar code in JQuery -
http://jsfiddle.net/tkfeo6p2/

I try this code using pure JavaScript. but failed.

```
var output = {}
var last_depth = 1;

data.forEach(function(val) {
    var depth;
    depth = val.level;
    if (depth > last_depth) {
      output[depth] = val.content;
    }
    output[depth] = val.content;
    return last_depth = depth;
});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is the solution that you are looking for.

Please find the steps for the same.

- Reduce the data array into a multi level structure lke below.

```js
[
  {
    "level": 1,
    "content": "First Lvl",
    "link": "#",
    "child": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "content": "Second Lvl",
        "link": "#",
        "child": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "content": "Third Lvl",
            "link": "#",
            "child": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "level": 2,
        "content": "Second Lvl 2",
        "link": "#",
        "child": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": 1,
    "content": "First Lvl 2",
    "link": "#",
    "child": []
  }
]
```

- The above mentioned array can be converted to template string by using recursive function.

Please find the working fiddle below.

```js
let data = [
    { level: 1, content: 'First Lvl', link: '#' },
    { level: 2, content: 'Second Lvl', link: '#' },
    { level: 3, content: 'Third Lvl', link: '#' },
    { level: 2, content: 'Second Lvl 2', link: '#' },
    { level: 1, content: 'First Lvl 2', link: '#' }
];
const formattedNode = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(acc.length > 0 && curr.level !== 1) {
        let node = acc;
        let index = curr.level;
        while (index > 1) {
            node = node[node.length - 1].child;
            index--;
        }
        node.push({ ...curr, child: [] });
    } else {
        acc.push({ ...curr, child: [] });
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

let templateStr = '<ul>';
formattedNode.forEach((node) => templateStr += parseNode(node));
templateStr += '</ul>';
function parseNode(node) {
    let tmpStr = '<li>';
    tmpStr += `<a href="${node.link}">${node.content}</a>`;
    if (node.child.length) {
        tmpStr += '<ul>';
        node.child.forEach((childNode) => {
            tmpStr += parseNode(childNode);
        })
        tmpStr += '</ul>';
    }
    tmpStr += '</li>';
    return tmpStr;
}
console.log(templateStr)
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = templateStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment#example

You should allow for list items which have the same depth but a different parent. Append/push to a collection prevents replacement at an index through equality assignment.